# How to implement enums with values in Scala 2.12.15

Tags: scala, enums

In Java, one can use (from https://www.baeldung.com/java-enum-values#adding-constructor)

```java
public enum Element {
    H("Hydrogen"),
    HE("Helium"),
    NE("Neon");

    public final String label;

    private Element(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

to construct Enums with string values, such that `NE.label` would yield `"Neon"`.

How do you do the same thing, but in Scala version 2.12.15? (Please show the above example translated to Scala)

Comment: The easiest solution is to use `Enumeration` and you can look up by string with `withName`, but there's concerns about type safety though it's usually not an issue

Comment: Scala 2.x `Enumeration` had some quirks and was not widely used. The accepted answer provides two most popular alternatives which are using ADTs or Enumeratum library. However, if you're on Scala 3, enums got redesigned entirely and using them is your best bet: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/enums/enums.html

Comment: Thanks for that comment! That is definitely what I'd want to use. Scala has done a great job at simplifying Java syntax, but it really went backwards with enums. The newer Scala 3.x syntax really addresses this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to create enums in **Scala** is through a basic ADT like this:

```scala
sealed abstract class Element(val label: String)
object Element {
  final case object H extends Element(label = "Hydrogen")
  final case object HE extends Element(label = "Helium")
  final case object NE extends Element(label = "Neon")
}
```

If you want some goodies, like getting the list of all elements or a `getByName` method, for free.
Then the best would be to combine the above with the [**Enumeratum**](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) library.